# Table Valued Function with parameter CTE expression result

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Is it possible to have a select statement that includes tvf and its parameter is the result of a CTE expression? Here is my code:

```
 ;with
 date_cte as
 (
    SELECT * FROM ExplodeDates('2012-10-09','2012-10-12')
 )
SELECT * FROM ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE
(
    SELECT QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),thedate,120),'''') thedate FROM date_cte
)
```

When I run this query, the error is Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. and Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Does it possible? Or I have some misconception with the CTE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have CTE in your SQLServer version then have [**CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operators too

```
;with date_cte as
 (
  SELECT * FROM ExplodeDates('2012-10-09','2012-10-12')
 )
  SELECT c.*
  FROM date_cte CROSS APPLY ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE(QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10), thedate, 120), '''')) c
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d60a6/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

If ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE were to take a scalar input, you could bracket the inner query to feed it a scalar value.

```
;with
 date_cte as
 (
    SELECT * FROM ExplodeDates('2012-10-09','2012-10-12')
 )
SELECT * FROM ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE
(
    (SELECT QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(10),thedate,120),'''') thedate FROM date_cte)
)
```

However, because `ufn_GET_ATTENDANCE` takes a user-defined table type as parameter, it is impossible to pass a CTE result.  Not even a compatible table variable unless it is of the EXACT defined type.

See these examples:

```
create type ud_type as table (A int)
GO
create function table_in(@in ud_type readonly)
returns table as
return select * from @in
GO

declare @tbl ud_type;
select * from table_in(@tbl)
-- ok
GO

declare @tbl table (A int);
select * from table_in(@tbl)
-- Operand type clash: table is incompatible with ud_type:
```

Comment: Note: if it's not clear, you can't pass a CTE because it's just a made up resultset with no implicit "type" and will not match the user defined table type. It must be a variable declared specifically as the user defined type.